# sql select - filter for the first row on seqence part

Tags: sql, select, view, filtering, mariadb

I got something tricky...

Given is a sequence of rows in a table:

```
int val
01  ii
03  jj
13  kk
16  ll
17  mm
22  nn
25  oo
```

I need a SQL select filtering me every lowest of the tenths:

```
int val
01  ii
13  kk
22  nn
```

So the sequence may be first divided into the areas 0*, 1* and 2* and on every part may be a min(int) executed.

The problem is: I got no idea to solve this in a kind SQL-statement i.e. for using it as a view.

I use MariaDB: 10.0.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.2

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
select a.int,b.val
from
(select floor((int + 9) / 10) * 10 as chck,min(int) as int from have
group by chck) a
left join
have b
on a.int = b.int;
```

Let me know in case of any doubts.

Comment: Happy to help!!